# Analogous concept for word::synonym, but for sentences

Tags: synonyms, linguistics

The best way I can ask this question is algebraically: "word is to synonym as sentence is to X"...what is X?

I'm looking for the name of the concept where two different sentences convey the same idea.

Comment: Like **rephrasing** or **rewording**?

Comment: @Davo yes exactly

Comment: Like **rewording** or **rephrasing**?

Comment: Perhaps ***to be served concurrently***?

Comment: There is no exact analogous single word for sentences. Two sentences 'have the same meaning', which is a predicate, not an adjective or noun.

Answer (score 1):

**[Rephrasing](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rephrasing)**, from TFD:

> re·phrase  (rē-frāz′)
>
> tr.v. re·phrased, re·phras·ing, re·phras·es
>
> To phrase again, especially to state in a new, clearer, or different way.

**[Rewording](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rewording)**, from TFD:

> re·word  (rē-wûrd′)
>
> tr.v. re·word·ed, re·word·ing, re·words
>
> 1. a. To change the wording of.
> 2. b. To state or express again in different words.

Answer (score 1):

A **[paraphrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraphrase)** is a restatement of text using other words.